# reRender rich:tabPanel without losing data

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

Using JSF 1.2 and Richfaces 3.3, I have this form:

```
<h:form>
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="client" id="tabPnl">
        <rich:tab label="MAIN_TAB">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.date}"/>
            <rich:calendar value="#{MyBean.date}">
                <f:validator validatorId="CalendarValidator" />
            </rich:calendar>
            <h:message for="DataInici" errorClass="error" />

            <h:outputText value="#{msg.selector}"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="select_val" value="#{MyBean.selectedItem}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.select_value}" itemValue="-1" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{MyBean.listOfItems}" />
                <f:validator validatorId="NumSelValidator" />
                <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="tabPnl" ajaxSingle="true" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:message for="select_val" errorClass="error" />
        </rich:tab>

        <rich:tab label="SUBTAB1" id="subtab1" rendered="#{MyBean.selectedItem == 1}">
            // form components such as inputText and/or SelectOneMenu.
        </rich:tab>

        <rich:tab label="SUBTAB2" id="subtab2" rendered="#{MyBean.selectedItem == 2}">
            // Other form components such as inputText and/or SelectOneMenu.
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>

    <h:commandButton value="#{msg.insert}" action="#{MyBean.insertData}">
</h:form>
```

At the begining, SUBTAB1 and SUBTAB2 are not rendered as the default value for `MyBean.selectedItem` is -1.

Firstly, the user picks a date in the `<rich:calendar>` component and, after that, it selects a value in the `<h:selectOneMenu>`. After that, the desired behaviour (what I want to achieve) is reRender the tabPanel without losing the data already introduced. Consequently, I expect the tabs `SUBTAB1` or `SUBTAB2` become rendered depending on what the value chosen in the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

**What I get**: The tabPanel is reRendered, the appropiate SUBTAB is rendered but the data introduced in the first tab is lost.

How can I render these tabs without losing the data already introduced? I've tried to reRender the specific tabs, but it dosen't make them become rendered (I suppose it only affects to their content).

Thank you in advance.

Note: All beans involved are Session scoped.

Comment: I submitted a similar question two days ago. I removed it because I thought the problem was due to design errors, but it wasn't. Sorry for having removed the question.

Comment: It looks like you have a request scoped managed bean to do the task. You can change it to session scoped or leave it at request scoped and assign `@KeepAlive` tag annotation to your managed bean class: `@KeepAlive public class MyBean{ ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that the inputs values are not processed on server.
Remove `ajaxSingle="true"` from `a4j:support`, so the whole form is processed when selectOneMenu value changes. You can use `process` attribute to limit the submitted area (in case you don't want to process the whole form).

> ajaxSingle
>
> Limits JSF tree processing (decoding, conversion, validation and model
>   updating) only to a component that sends the request. Boolean. Default
>   value is "false".

Comment: Thanks for your response, It has clarified me how my form was actually working. Removing `ajaxSingle=true` from my `a4j:support` has solved the problem, but now the fields fail to validate if they are not properly filled, so the `rich:tabPanel` is not reRendered. Is it possible to skip validations but keep the values? I just want them to be performed when the user presses the "Insert" button.

Comment: @jimrodrigg Invalid values cannot be set into the model. If something needs to be changed on selectOneMenu make process only fields which must be valid to perform the operation. In you case I believe a4j:support could get process="calendarId, selectOneMenuId".

Comment: In fact, the whole form needs to be processed =) Thank you very much for your clarifications.